# zip file is not getting created, How to fix this?

Tags: php, zip

I am trying to create a ZIP file.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip_name = time().".zip";
$zip->open($zip_name,  ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($zip->open($zip_name) === TRUE)
{
    $zip->addFile('Hello.txt', 'newname.txt');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
   echo 'failed';
}
```

But when I run this code its showing failed. Why?

Comment: You're calling `$zip->open` twice. Trying saving the first one in a variable and use that in the `if` condition.

Comment: @AlirezaFallah, He did. See the third line in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This works.. Tested

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip_name = time().".zip";
$res = $zip->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    file_put_contents('somefile.txt',"I am writing something to the file");
    $zip->addFile('somefile.txt', 'filenameinsidezip.txt');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: The `$zip->open` returns a `mixed` type not a `boolean` . That was the error. Also, the `addFile` was not able to find the `Hello.txt`

Comment: and the mixed value is empty of course, because else part is executing , that is NOT the error

Comment: Nope, the answer which i posted earlier went inside the `if` and displayed an `ok`.